# messenger like functionality

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am building a chat server on PHP. More like facebook one to one chat. I can't figure out the query which displays the messages of the two users who are chatting. I have a list of people who i can chat with and i am doing this through anchor tag. But the messages of the sender are visible in chat windows even though the sender has never messaged them. I can't figure out a way to display no messages if the user has never chatted with a user in the chat list.

here is the code for the list

```
echo"<a href='chat/public/01_index.php?id2=$xyz'>Chat</a>";
```

Here is the query

```
 public function getMessages($rid,$userid) {
   $messages = array();
  $query = <<<QUERY
  SELECT 
  `chat`.`message`, 
  `chat`.`sent_on`,
  `chat`.`rec_id`,
  `user1`.`id`, 
  `user1`.`first_name`
  FROM `user1`
  JOIN `chat`
  ON `chat`.`user_id` = `user1`.`id` WHERE `user1`.`id`=$rid or `user1`.`id`=$userid
   ORDER BY `sent_on`
  QUERY;
```

Comment: Could you give us more details of your application? And use prepared requests instead of concatenating values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are saying where user 1 = either of the participating users, but you are not checking user 2.

```
 public function getMessages($rid,$userid) {
   $messages = array();
  $query = <<<QUERY
  SELECT 
  `chat`.`message`, 
  `chat`.`sent_on`,
  `chat`.`rec_id`,
  `user1`.`id`, 
  `user1`.`first_name`
  FROM `user1`
  JOIN `chat`
  ON `chat`.`user_id` = `user1`.`id` WHERE (`user1`.`id`=$rid AND `user2`.`id` = $userid) or (`user1`.`id`=$userid AND `user2`.`id` = $rid)
   ORDER BY `sent_on`
  QUERY;
```

Comment: user2 table doesn't exist. i have two tables: user1 from which the id of the logged in user is retrieved  and join occurs between them. in the chat table i have details of the messages i.e senderid,receiverid,message,sent_on etc